# How to align rotated multi-line x axis text in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a example of what I currently have:

```
x <- head(mtcars)
x$rn <- rownames(x)
x$rn[5] <- 'Hornet\nSportabout'

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(x, aes(x = rn, y = mpg)) + geom_point() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
ggsave('test.png', width = 3, height = 3)
```

The plot looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, `'Hornet\nSportabout'` is too close to next one and I would like to move it a little bit left. The expected x-axis text looks like this one:

[image]

I thought that I should set `vjust = 0.5`, but this will also move axis text down. I also tried severial combinations of `vjust` and `hjust` and still can not get desired output. Is there a way to get `axis.text` aligned as shown in the second plot (manually created with libreoffice draw) with ggplot2?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Any amount you move one line left/right or up/down (with hjust and vjust) will move all of them the same amount, so the gap will still be too small. I really advise my colleagues strongly against any angle besides 0 or 90 for that reason; makes it too crowded.

Comment: Potentially you could change it to "Hornet\nSportabout\n" to try to split the narrow gap onto both sides, but it's hackist and it'll never look evenly spaced when you look closely.

Comment: I thought it would be hard to read if the angle is 90.

Comment: If easy reading is a priority, I would usually put text labels on the vertical axis instead (using `coord_flip` where necessary, for some geoms). Otherwise there could always be scenarios where even the nicest multi-line x-axis labels look ugly. E.g. labels are too long / contain too many line breaks, font size is too large relative to plot size, etc.

Comment: @Z.Lin, thanks for the suggestion. The problem is that the y-axis label is also quite long and too many (~ 40).

Answer (score 1):

There currently is no ggplot native way to do this I am afraid. But you can use `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(lineheight=0.75))` to make the problem less severe, or disappear using `angle=90` and `vjust=0.5` or hack around on the level of `grid` as demonstrated below:

```r
x <- head(mtcars)
x$rn <- rownames(x)
x$rn[5] <- 'Hornet\nSportabout'

library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
```

```r
breaks <- sort(unique(x$rn))
labels <- breaks
n_linebrks_of_labels <- stringr::str_count(labels, "\n")

ggplot(x, aes(x = rn, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks= breaks, labels=labels) +
  guides(x= guide_axis(angle=90)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(lineheight=0.75))
```

[image]

```r
labels <- gsub("\n", "  \n",labels) 
labels[n_linebrks_of_labels>0] <- paste0(labels[n_linebrks_of_labels>0], "  ")

p1 <- ggplot(x, aes(x = rn, y = mpg)) + geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks= breaks, labels=labels) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,
                                   vjust=0.5,
                                   hjust=1,
                                   lineheight=0.75
  ))


p1 <- ggplot_build(p1)
g1 <- ggplot_gtable(p1)

g1$grobs[[7]]$children[[2]]$grobs[[2]]$children[[1]]$y <- unit(rep(1,6), "npc")
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(g1)
```

[image]

```r
#original for reference
ggplot(x, aes(x = rn, y = mpg)) + geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,
                                   vjust=1,
                                   hjust=1
  ))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This plot is exported with default `width` and `height` from `Rstudio`.

[picture exported with default values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp9Xz.png)

Also you can do the same using the package `grDevices`. The code will be like this:

```
library(grDevices)
png("test1.png",width = 592, height = 379, units = "px")
ggplot(ggplot(x, aes(x = rn, y = mpg)) + geom_point() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1)) 
dev.off()
```

Now one can see the file `test1.png` in the current working directory.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. This sill produce axis text anchored at top right position, what I want is more like anchoring at middle right posiiton.